# Nested Child UI component is not working on keypress event in Parent component in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I am trying to add shortcut to open nested child UI Tab component through keyboard keypress event. But, to load Child nested Tab component, first parent should be loaded.
Below is UI tree:

- |--Parent Component
- |----Child Component -- It contains 4 tabs.
- |------Child Tab
  Component -- First Tab.

Keypress event is written inside Parent Component,

```
@HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if(event.code === "KeyR") {
        //here storing event details in service
        MyService.store({
            key: HANDLE_KEY_EVENT,
            data: event
        })
    }
}
```

And in Child component, Child nested Tab should get open on the basis of subscribing the stored event details. Below is code snippet:

```
private readonly subscriber: Subscription[] = [];

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.subscriber.push(
            MyService.observe(HANDLE_KEY_EVENT).subscribe((event)=>{
                if(event.code === "KeyR"){
                    openTab()
                }
            })
        )
    }
```

But openTab() function is not calling with above code snippet i.e. written inside subscribe.
In below code snippet openTab() function is calling, if it written directly inside ngOnInit() i.e. without subscribe:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    openTab()
}
```

My requirement is to write openTab() function issue inside subscribe.

**So, please help me in fixing above issue.**

Below is the implementation of store and observe function inside MyService.

```
private subject:Subject<any> = new Subject();

public store(key:string,data:any){
    const event = {
        name: key,
        data: data
    };
    this.subject.next(event);
}

public observe(key:string):Observable<any>{
    return new Observable<any>((observer)=>{
        this.subject.subscribe(res=>{
            if(res.name === key){
                observer.next(res.data);
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: I think you need to post your methods `store` and `observe` of `MyService`.

Comment: In your function "store" of the service you make "something" (I imagine a "observe.next(..)")?

Comment: @Eliseo I have updated implementation logic for store and observe function.

Comment: @Eddi I have posted implementation of store and observe function of MyService

Comment: @user2648519, There's some errors in your code, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some errors in your code

First, you need inject in constructor the service, both in child and parent

```
  constructor(private MyService:MyService){}
```

Your function store should destructure the arguments, else give you error "expect 2 arguments but only 1 is give". See the destructure is in the way `{variable1,variable2,...}:{variable1:typeOfVariable1,variable2:typeOfVariable2,...}`

```
public store({key,data}:{key:string,data:any}){
    const event = {
        name: key,
        data: data
    };
    this.subject.next(event);
}
```

You need use "this" in service: `this.MyService`.

NOTE: I leave your name, but generally we use the variable in lower case:       `constructor(private myService:MyService){}`

I made a little [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-pjvzwd?file=src%2Fmain.ts) I hope help you